# What does it mean to have multiple instances of React?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, npm, dependency-management

For context: I've encountered a problem in my React application (using `npm` + Create React App + TypeScript) where it appears I have more than one copy of React in the app. This is based off diagnostic snippet given in the [React documentation](https://reactjs.org/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning.html#duplicate-react) where you test that `window.React1 === window.React2`.

This question isn't asking for solutions to fix that (I'll investigate that separately). Instead, I'd like to know what it *means* to have duplicates of a library. How does that end up delivered to the browser as part of the big bundled script that CRA generates, and which duplicate is selected when I write `import React from 'react'` in source code? How might duplicate libraries occur, and why does `npm` allow this?

The answer might be, "go off and learn about how JS package management and bundling works", which might be very reasonable, but if anyone had any specific answers and pointers to more resources to learn, I'd be very grateful. TIA.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, there are some questions that need to be answered first such as are you using any third party packages on-top of your CRA project. This message will also predominantly show if you have just started development on consumable react components for the first time. A lot of these projects get around this issue by bundling their application with react and react-dom marked as an external dependency to ensure they all point to the same 'copy'. Another issue is that you have been pulling in dependencies with react not marked as a peer dependency which causes version mismatches

Comment: My last comment was too long but a good way to check if you have multiple copies of React is run the `npm ls react` command.

Comment: Thanks @Win, as I mentioned, I'm not asking how to fix the specific problem with duplicate React in this question (I might do that elsewhere). Instead, I'm asking a more general question about what it means to have a duplicate library in this context, how does that play out with npm and import resolution, and so on.

Comment: Like, I said it's normally derived from a third party module stand point in terms of development. Unless you install or a package or are building your own external components you should not face this problem. As for looking into the problem further, I don't know really know what to suggest other than trying to seep through the 'Hooks can only be called inside the body...' error which can invoke the error you mentioned via github issues on the repo here: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/13991

Comment: Since StackOverflow is aimed at specific problems rather than broad questions like this, it might be worth hitting up the react issues tracker and opening a question there and hopefully someone can give you a better perspective / answer from there

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First off, let's clearly state what a duplicate library can mean in this context. If you were to unpack your bundled project, you might find multiple versions of React, for example, 16 and 17. This is a good framing to keep in mind for the rest of the discussion.

While most of the time, this kind of duplication is a mistake, there are cases where this may be desirable. Let's cover that first before getting to your specific case.

A good example of where this can be beneficial is big distributed development teams that use something similar to [the micro frontends architecture](https://micro-frontends.org/). Shortly explained, two teams might be responsible for two different parts of the page with their own set of dependencies, without affecting the other:

```
 ┌───────────────────────────┐
 │          Webpage          │
 │ ┌──────────┐ ┌──────────┐ │
 │ │ React 16 │ │ React 17 │ │
 │ └──────────┘ └──────────┘ │
 └───────────────────────────┘
```

While this may seem like waste of space, the development team has made a tradeoff here: they have a slightly bigger page load, but they reduce the need for inter-team syncing regarding versions. Perhaps one team is ready to use the latest version, but the other still needs to do work before they're ready to update. Another good example is legacy code — you may have code that works well, but is unmaintained so you choose to just ship it as is as long as it works:

```
 ┌──────────────────────────────┐
 │           Webpage            │
 │ ┌───────────┐ ┌────────────┐ │
 │ │ Angular 1 │ │ Angular 10 │ │
 │ └───────────┘ └────────────┘ │
 └──────────────────────────────┘
```

Hopefully the above illustrates why setups like this are allowed by the package manager: they can be desirable, and in some cases, very beneficial.

The way this can be set up varies as widely as there are project setups, but one of the approaches to the above is having subprojects of some sort, each with their own `package.json`:

```
project
├─ package.json
├─ one subproject
│  └─ package.json
└─ another subproject
   └─ package.json
```

In the above case, imports in `one subproject` would be set up to resolve by the `package.json` in that folder, and imports in `another subproject` would be set up to resolve by their `package.json`. One common way to configure module resolution is via the [Webpack `resolve` configuration](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/), but other approaches are of course possible.

Hopefully the above explains why this is possible, as well as some hints as to when it might be a good consideration.

As mentioned before though, most of the time this is a mistake. Most users don't intentionally want to do this, and including the same library with minute differences, for example React 17.0.0 and React 17.0.1 is not what they meant to do. For the common use case, the above two should be practically interchangeable.

There are a number of ways to end up with this issue, but the most common one is incorrectly configured [peer dependencies](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/dependency-types/). Peer dependencies are a way for libraries, component packs, etc to specify what they rely on, while allowing the dependency to be shared. A common example would be a UI component library that supports any React version as long as it's newer than, say, React 16. If your project uses React 17, you can then happily pull in that component library and have a single version of React in your code base.

The error occurs when the library author (unintentionally) configures the dependency on React 16 as a regular dependency, not a peer dependency. In that case, the author is essentially saying the library needs React 16 and doesn't allow anything else, and you would end up with two versions of React installed.

All of the above is very broad strokes, and brushing over a lot of details, but hopefully this gives you some insight into the problem you're solving.

Comment: Thank you for the informative answer. I had the same situation as you have described, my project ended up with two React versions, `17.0.2` and `>=16.8.0` which come from some other third parts which I don't have control over. How can I fix this (when I removed manually it worked but there should be another straightforward way)

Comment: @HumoyunAhmad This depends mostly on how your project is set up. In simple cases you can use [`resolutions` if you're using Yarn](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/selective-version-resolutions/) or [`overrides` if you're using NPM](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/configuring-npm/package-json#overrides). If that is not sufficient in your case, you will most likely have to reconfigure your build tooling.